# What does &** mean?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers

In ·std::unique_ptr· code in file "memory", I see operator overloading functions as

```
typename tr1::add_reference<_Ty>::type operator*() const
{   
   // return reference to object
   return (*this->_Myptr);
}

pointer operator->() const
{
  // return pointer to class object
   return (&**this);
}
```

What does the `&**` mean in the second function? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to the `unique_ptr` object.

`*this` is a reference to the `unique_ptr` object.

`**this` is dereferencing the `unique_ptr` using `operator*` (i.e. `*this->_Myptr`).

So, `&**this` is a pointer to the object pointed at by the `unique_ptr` (i.e. `&(*this->_Myptr)`).

Answer (score 5):

As per the posted code, `**this` is invoking `operator*` overload which returns a reference to an object. so `&**this` becomes address of the returned object.

In other words, `**this` is same as `(*this->_Myptr)`, and `&**this` is same as `&(*this->_Myptr)`.